# Maximo Anywhere runtime deployment error

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We have Maximo Anywhere 761 on iOS for our client. Everything was working OK until yesterday, but since yesterday logs show Noclassfound exception while starting the runtime. And on mobilefirst console, it shows no runtime installed. I have tried reinstalling the runtime number of times but the error persists.

Here is what the logs show:

```
[9/14/17 10:22:26:921 EDT] 00000070 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.gadgets.serving.ClientConfigProfileServlet
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.loadClass(WASAnnotationHelper.java:829)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.collectClasses(WASAnnotationHelper.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.<init>(WASAnnotationHelper.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelperManager.getAnnotationHelper(WASAnnotationHelperManager.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.handOffReferenceData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:938)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

[9/14/17 10:22:26:921 EDT] 00000070 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.gadgets.serving.BinaryApplicationDownloadServlet
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.loadClass(WASAnnotationHelper.java:829)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.collectClasses(WASAnnotationHelper.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.<init>(WASAnnotationHelper.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelperManager.getAnnotationHelper(WASAnnotationHelperManager.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.handOffReferenceData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:938)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

[9/14/17 10:22:26:937 EDT] 00000070 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.loadClass(WASAnnotationHelper.java:829)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.collectClasses(WASAnnotationHelper.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.<init>(WASAnnotationHelper.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelperManager.getAnnotationHelper(WASAnnotationHelperManager.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.handOffReferenceData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:938)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

Answer (score 0):

These class not found errors are usually due to a misconfiguration of the war at deployment. Specifically the classloader options for the war. Was a war file redeployed recently?  Take a look through the Mobilefirst docs for classloader configuration relating to parent first or parent last class loading

Comment: Thanks Scott. After looking at the folder structure, we found a missing folder and on start up, some of the classes were loaded from that. We restored the previous working state and redeployed the war file and now the apps are available under runtime.